# Sendmail migration: Replicating all incoming mails to another mailserver

Tags: email, postfix, sendmail

I am migrating a mailserver running sendmail `8.14.3` to a postfix server.  The `MDA` on the new server is `Dovecot`. In order to ensure a seamless transition, it would be best if incoming mails are delivered to both servers simultaneously.

I've heard about the `SMART_HOST` and `nullcient` options in sendmail, but I'm not sure if this works in the way I need it to. What I need is all incoming mails also delivered to the new server, leaving the existing configuration untouched, as they should be delivered to the mailboxes on the old server as well.

Mails are sent to an address like `test@mydomain.com` and should be delivered to `mx1.mydomain.com` (old) and `mx2.mydomain.com` (new). So `mx1` should forward a copy to `mx2`.

Dual MX Records are not enough as the one server would only be contacted when the other one isn't reachable - while both should be receiving the mail.

Maybe another option would be to configure `sendmail` to deliver directly to `Dovecot` on the new server via `lmtp`? Or maybe just `rsync` the mailboxes on the two servers. But I'm not sure if that's compatible.

**UPDATE:** It's not the same format: on the old server, there are just plain old files for each mailbox, while `Dovecot` creates a `cur`, `new` `tmp` structure in each user's mail directory. However, in the end, files with a similar format reside in those directories. The speration string is different though. Maybe it's possible to translate the old format and copy it to the new server periodically? Would that somehow interfere with `Dovecot`? And where could I place the copies on the new server so that `Dovecot` won't be affected while still recognising them?

I hope there is some kind of workaround for that.

---

**System Indormation**

Number of mailboxes: ~100-200

Old Server:

```
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 6.0
sendmail 8.14.3
mails are delivered to "real"/"passwd" users
Other Serives: apache2, mysql, other miscellaneous
```

New Server:

```
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9
postfix
dovecot
mails are delivered to virtual users/SQL
Other services: apache2, mysql, other miscellaneous
```

Current MX entry for reference:

```
mydomain.com.    IN      MX      0 mx1.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.    IN      MX      1 mx2.mydomain.com.
```

Comment: This isn't so much redirection as replication of incoming emails. Redirection could be handled at the MX level. Replication is harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this right now but I'm fairly sure `sendmail` understands entries in `/etc/aliases` of the form

```
fred: fred, fred@otherserver
```

(If it goes into a mad loop, prefix the second `fred` with a backslash `\`.)

Then it's a straightforward extract from `/etc/passwd` into the `aliases` file. And remember to run `newaliases` (?) to update the internal `sendmail` database.

Here is an example snippet to generate the lines that would be appended. It considers only users whose UID is in the range { 1000 ≤ uid < 65000 }.

```
[ ! -f /etc/aliases.save ] && cp -p /etc/aliases /etc/aliases.save

(
    cat /etc/aliases.save
    echo
    getent passwd |
        awk -F: '$3>=1000 && $3<65000 {printf "%s: %s, %s@mx2.mydomain.com\n", $1, $1, $1}'
) >/etc/aliases

newaliases
```

Comment: I thought of that, but the other server accepts mail under `fred@mydomain.com` only (the same as the old server as the addresses are supposed to stay the same). So could I somehow remap that on the new server?

Comment: Or would the new server just accept something like `fred@mx2.mydomain.com`?

Comment: If it's set up to accept `mx2.mydomain.com` as an alias for its real target name `mydomain.com` yes that should work.

Comment: I've updated my question with sample mx records to hopefully clarify what I mean by that.

Comment: So on the new server, I should add the second domain `mx2.mydomain.com` and enter an alias for all the users there that points to the user at `mydomain.com`?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I'm testing it right now. The alias on the new server works as expected, but `fred: fred, fred@mx2.mydomain.com` does not seem to work yet. I've tried with and without backslash and I did run `newaliases` and even restarted sendmail. It gets delivered to `fred@mydomain.com`, but not to the new one. If I directly send to `fred@mx2.mydomain.com` it is delivered to the new one.

Comment: If I just put `fred: fred@mx2.mydomain.com` it doesn't get delivered to either of them.

Comment: I think it's working, but postfix does: `NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown` `Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname`

Comment: I guess that's due to `smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination`. Do you happen to know how to "whitelist" my one domainname?

Comment: I think it's working properly now. The old sendmail server may be a bit misconfigured. I've added the old server's ip to `mynetworks` in postfix. Many thanks for your patience! :)